# Angular 7: Problem with updating global variable

Tags: angular, typescript

In the following code, while I'm trying to access the global variable it returns undefined. How can I update the variable so that it is available for use in another function?

```
episodes: EpisodeModel[] = [];

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.episodesService.getAllEpisodes().subscribe(data => {
        this.episodes = data;
        console.log(this.episodes); // shows array
        this.showEpisodes(); // function to display episodes on the page - sets event listener ('click', this.showEpisodeInfo) - works
    }
}
```

```
    showEpisodeInfo(event) {
        console.log(event); // works
        console.log(this.episodes); // returns undefined
    }
```

I omitted some details since it was too large for posting:

```
     showEpisodes(): void {
        let episodes = this.episodes;
        let document = this.shows.nativeElement.contentDocument;
        let genres = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('genre')[0].getElementsByTagName('path'));
        for (let i in episodes) {
          let episode = <any>episodes.find((e: any) => {
            return e.getAttribute('title') == episodes[i].genre;
          });
          let episodesGroup = document.getElementById('episodes');
          if (episodes[i].episodeType.toLowerCase() === 'fantasy') {
            let episode = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'svg');
            episode.setAttributeNS(null, 'style', 'overflow: visible;')
            let episodeThumbnail = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'circle');
            episodeThumbnail.setAttributeNS(null, 'class', 'episode');
            episodeThumbnail.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', 'black');
            episodeThumbnail.setAttributeNS(null, 'overflow', 'visible');
            episodeThumbnail.addEventListener("click", this.showEpisodeInfo);
            let episodeTitle = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'title');
            episodeTitle.innerHTML = episodes[i].episodeTitle;
            episodeThumbnail.appendChild(episodeTitle);
            episode.appendChild(episodeThumbnail);
            episodesGroup.appendChild(episode);
          }}}
```

Comment: What is the reason to use `setTimeout`? Its returning `undefined` due to the block getting executed outside Angular zone.

Comment: We have no idea of how showEpisodeInfo is being called. The bug is in the code you chose not to show.

Comment: I don't think there's a bug in there really, that's why I decided to skip it. It's just a function setting a bunch of attributes as stated in the comment in which the episodes array is used to retrieve information.

Comment: Show us how `showEpisodeInfo` is called.

Comment: There is a bug. And also probably a bad practice. If you want help, post the code of showEpisodes.

Comment: I have just updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific bug is caused by

```
episodeThumbnail.addEventListener("click", this.showEpisodeInfo);
```

which should be

```
episodeThumbnail.addEventListener("click", event => this.showEpisodeInfo(event));
```

But your code completely misuses Angular. You're not supposed to do DOM manipulation, nor add event listeners, from a component. That's the role of the template.

The component should just modify its state, and the template should use directives (*ngIf, *ngFor, etc.), property binding, and event binding (`(click)="..."`) to display the state.

Read [the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax), because you're currently missing the whole point of Angular.

Comment: Thank you! I'm a newcomer in Angular so I mostly use it for experimentation purposes at the moment. What would be your suggestion on how to combine Angular with SVG manipulation?

Comment: AFAIK, you can use svg elements the same way you're using html elements.